# Create a union type based on 2 enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I have 2 enums and I want to declare a new type based some operation on 2 enums, is there a way to do it?

```
export enum Actions {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c'
}
export enum Prefix {
  X = 'x',
  Y = 'y'
}
```

And I want a new type which is a concat of 2 enums

`type AP = "ax" | "ay" | "bx" | "by" | "cx" | "cy"`

Comment: Not possible to perform string literal type concatenations

Answer (score 0):

### Hello,

I just read through the question, and i had definitely nothing to do.

I saw the comments and I don't like sentences containing `Not possible` , etc.

### Anyways:

I started to play around and I produced something which is maybe worth it to share .The code below demonstrates a "dynamic" typing of enum keys. I created a type which holds your combination as nested objects. So therefore, Your type value `ab` would be represented as `a.b` in the "typed" `enum`.

Just look at the code, it should make it a little clear.

```
export enum Actions {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C'
}
export enum Prefix {
    X = 'X',
    Y = 'Y'
}

type actType = keyof typeof Actions
type preType = keyof typeof Prefix

type resultsArr = {[key1 in actType]: {[key2 in preType]: string}};


// structure of resultsArr:
/*
    A: {
        X: string, // holds 'AX'
        Y: string // holds 'AY'
    },
    B: {
        X: string, // holds 'BX'
        Y: string  // ...
    },
    C: {
        X: string,
        Y: string
    }

*/
```

### maybe worth to try...

If you are able to produce objects like this after your manipulation, It would maybe be possible to type something useful according to your problem.

Such objects would then be easily to normalise to the string values you have.
You will also have to hardcode all the enums you have and concat them "by hand".

But anyways, I wanted to share..
Cheers.

Comment: But this is more of a runtime solution... it's not like if you write `A.X` you will have the string literal type that represents the string `AX`. That is what is asked. Having the literal type has all sorts of advantages, when creating mapped types, or using a value of such a type to access o strictly typed object.

Comment: Thanks Silvan! 
But I am looking for a type that represents the string "AX". 
It may not be possible today after all as Titian says

Comment: As mentioned. I just wanted to share. I know it's not an "answer.."